# Submit a form and get 404 empty response back

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I have a servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.timelessmind.ttms.server.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/attachment</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in the code, I have a submit `FormPanel` with a `FileUpload`:

```
form.setAction("/attachment");
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
```

And submit button:

```
submitButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

SubmitCompleteHandler:

```
Window.alert(event.getResults());
```

And the response is like:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.
```

The requested source is an empty bracket, which I could not figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your firebug network console to see where exactly is the form submitted.

It is most certainly submitting in `http://yoururl:8080/attachment` instead of `http://yoururl:8080/MyApp/attachment`

To solve your problem, try removing the slash at the beginning:

```
form.setAction("attachment");
```

Otherwise, add your application context:

```
form.setAction("/MyApp/attachment");
```

Comment: Or use `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "attachment"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try complete url in action method(`http://yoururl:8080/MyApp/attachment`)